# Setting up PeerJS With GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, port, peerjs

I'm unable to make `peerjs` connect to my server. I have setup a GAE-app with the [peerjs-server](https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server) running on it. The server is running fine since I can go the the `peerjs` endpoint and get the default response (`{"name":"PeerJS Server" etc...` ).

However, I'm unable to connect to that server from a loca file.

In my file, I have setup the following code:

```
        const peer = new Peer(peer_id, {host: '[somepath].appspot.com', path: '/p2p-broker'});

        peer.on('open', (id)=>{
            console.log('Peer id: ' + id);
        });
```

In theory, `peer.on('open', ...` should trigger immediately, right? I don't get any action at all. I have setup connection callbacks on my server side that inform of new connections (tested locally!) through the terminal, but those don't trigger on in the GAE version at all.

I've tried getting the port on which my `peerjs` server is running through logs, and including that info in the `Peer`-constructor, but this immediately throws an error (apart from not working through the browser either).

I'm pretty sure there is no connection happening whatsoever.

What am I doing wrong? What port do I have to specify?

Comment: Is this a firewall problem? What port are you using?

Comment: I'm posting the port that is set through the environment variable when starting the server through the console. There, it says 8080. But I'm doubtful that this is the port that is finally visible to the outside world. I don't know how to figure that one out though. I've tried accessing the peerjs endpoint through my browser, which works as described, but not if I include the port: `[mypath].appspot.com:8080/p2p-broker`. I've also tried with port `80` in my webapp, doesn't work either.

Comment: How would I find out the port of my app from GCloud console?

Comment: I don't know how to work out the port. When you say you have access the endpoint with the browser, is that with https:? If so, it's on port 443. It's quite possible that port gets routed to port 8080 on the docker instance itself (by something like NGINX). Not sure if you need to open additional ports so that your app can work, or if you can just use port 443 (although it needs to talk over https, which is a different protocol)

Comment: Yes, it's using https! I knew I was overseeing a trivial detail. It's not completely solved yet, but I'm progressing. Turned off https for now. Thank you!

Comment: I've decided to use a different library, it's simply to much of a hassle. If you want to write an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access the endpoint with the browser, is that with https:? If so, it's on port 443.

It's quite possible that port gets routed to port 8080 on the docker instance itself (by something like NGINX).

Not sure if you need to open additional ports so that your app can work, or if you can just use port 443 (although it needs to talk over https, which is a different protocol)